# Prove that $\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{kg(x^2)}{1+k^3[g(x^2)]^2}$ does not converge uniformly on the real line

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Suppose $g: \mathbb R_{\ge 0}\to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ is a continuous bijective function. Prove that the series $$\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{kg(x^2)}{1+k^3[g(x^2)]^2}$$ is not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb R$.

If I knew the sum of the series, I could use the negation of the definition of the uniform convergence of partial sums, but since I don't know the  limit of partial sums (and how to find one), I cannot do this.  How can I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried with any specific examples just to try to gain an intuition as to what breaks down? (I’m not entirely certain, just throwing out what I’d try.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be a continuous, bijective function from $\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$.  Furthermore, let $S(x)$ be the function given by the series

$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ng(x^2)}{1+n^3g^2(x^2)}$$

where we denote the $N$'th partial sum of $S(x)$ by $S_N(x)$.   Clearly, $S(x)$ is convergent for every $x$.

We wish to show that the convergence fails to be uniform on $[0,\infty)$.

---

Note that $S(x)$ *does* converge uniformly on $[x_0,\infty)$ for all $x_0>0$.

---

Inasmuch as $g$ is bijective, we can let $y=g(x^2)$ and analyze the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}$ for $y\in [0,\infty)$.

To show that the convergence is *not* uniform for $y\in [0,\infty)$, we will use the negation of uniform convergence, namely that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\ge 1$ there exists a number $N'>N$ and a $y\in [0,\infty)$ such that

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}\right|\ge \epsilon$$

Proceeding, we have with $y=1/(N+1)^{3/2}$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}\right|&=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{n/(N+1)^{3/2}}{1+\left(\frac{n}{N+1}\right)^3}\\\\
&\ge \sum_{n=N+1}^{2N+2}\frac{n/(N+1)^{3/2}}{1+\left(\frac{n}{N+1}\right)^3}\\\\
&\ge N\frac{1}{9(N+1)^{1/2}}\\\\
&\ge \frac{1}{9\sqrt 2}
\end{align}$$

So, we have found a number $\epsilon=\frac{1}{9\sqrt 2}>0$, such that for all $N$, there exists a number $y=1/(N+1)^{3/2}$ such that

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{ny}{1+n^3y^2}\right|\ge \epsilon$$

which negates the uniform convergence.   And we are done!

Comment: Could you clarify what general idea you are using? I would think one needs to disprove the uniform convergence of partial sums by negating the definition, but you're doing something different, and for now I can't seem to understand what exactly (and also how you're using the bijectivity of $g$).

Comment: @user5579085 I've edited quite a bit to provide a clearer, step-by-step explanation and "clean up" the previous analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! It seems you have a typo in your negation of the definition: shouldn't your $N$ be $N'$ in the inequality? Otherwise $N'$ plays no role. And I still don't get the part with bijectivity. Why can we "let" $y=g(x^2)$? In particular, does the fact that there is $g(x^2)$ (and not just $g(x)$) in the original series play any role?

Comment: Since the negation holds for all $N$, we can choose and $N'$.  Since $g$ is bijecive and continuous, then for $y=1/(N+1)^{3/2}$, we can find a number $x_N$ such that $g(x_N^2)=y$.  The square on $x$ keeps the domain of $x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}_{x\ge0}$.

Comment: So can I cross out "a number $N' > N$ and" from your negation since $N'$ doesn't participate in the inequality that follows this sentence? I thought you should have $N'$ in the inequality, and after that you could say "set $N'=N$". For the my bijectivity question, seems you only used surjectivity, do we need injectivity at all?

Comment: In general, we'd only need one such $N'>N$.  Here, for every $N$, all values $N'\ge N$ work.